# The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\System32" is not a file of a symlink

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I really don't know what to do.
Can somebody help?
it's on vscode

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Comment: For people having similar issue using Ubuntu. [VSCode Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187600/vscode-integrated-terminal-failed-to-launch/68387345#68387345)

Comment: For people having similar issue on Ubuntu. [VSCode Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187600/vscode-integrated-terminal-failed-to-launch)

Answer (score 1):

This is because it cannot find the `.exe` executable file, you can fix it with the following settings:

1. If you use `cmd.exe` to execute the script, use:

> `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"`

2. If you use `PowerShell.exe` to execute the script, use:

> ```
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
> ```

For more, you could also refer to: [Terminal.integrated.shell.windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove deleted files from your workspace in visual studio code(like erase the history of open files/folder).it works for me