# VSCode integrated terminal failed to launch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal, symlink

VSCode integrated terminal failed to launch and the error showed up:

> The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "bash" is not a file of a symlink.

Tried to look for solution in official troubleshoot page but can't really figured the cause of the problem.

Starting an external terminal (gnome-terminal) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> is fine.

Also tried to re-install VSCode, removing cache etc. still the same issues. Happens to almost all my Ubuntu computer.

There is a similar fix in Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020049/16346600, but how to do it in Linux? More particularly I can't find this `terminal.integrated.shell.linux`.

OS: Ubuntu18.04 LTS

VSCode: Version 1.57.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like VSCode somehow cannot find the path to executable for default profile "bash".

I fix by providing the exact binary path to `bash`.

Inside `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
  "bash": {
    "path": "/bin/bash"
  },
  ...
}
```