# How can I add a python interpreter for vs code and check the path of my shell?

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, cmder

I am a beginner with programming. I have a problem with my **python interpreter**(or that is what I think). I installed **vs code** as an editor, **python extension**(from Microsoft) and **cmder**(mini version) as a terminal. When I run the python code in vs code, a message appear and tells me that:
**"The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" does not exist."**

So what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Too add a Python Interpreter, you can follow [this official documantation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Also, you can follow [this QA on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007072/the-terminal-process-failed-to-launch-path-to-shell-executable-c-windows-syst) which has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` instead of `C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Have you configured `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` in the settings.json file? For example:

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell",
      "path": [
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
      ],

      "args": ["-NoLogo"]
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
  },
```

Can you remove it or configure it to the right path?

**Update:**

Sorry for that, I forgot you are a beginner with programming.

Could you find `powershell.exe` under:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Or

`C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

If you can find it in the `System32` folder, you can copy the above configuration to the settings.json file.

You can select `File -> Preferences -> Settings` to open the settings(shortcut of `Ctrl+,`). You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) for more details.

If you want to know more, you can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27915).

Comment: I respect that you answered me but can you tell me the steps I must follow to reach json file and change the path. Note: I did not configure the path.

Comment: @Haider Suhail Sorry for that, could you have look at the update?